# Class to wrap any Shape?

Tags: java, awt, shapes

I am creating custom shape class which is simply some selection of other shapes, defined by constructor parameter.

So, I have the following class heading:

```
public class SetShape implements Shape {

private final Shape shape;
```

In constructor I set the shape field and then I am to implement all Shape interface methods, delegating them to that field.

Is it possible to automate this somehow? Is there any class already defined for this? Can `GeneralPath` be such a class?

What is the difference between some `Shape` instance and `GeneralPath` instance, initialized with former `Shape` instance?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do. Do you just want a class to have a `Collection<Shape> myShapes` in it? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Try the [`Polygon` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html) or [`Area` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html). Especially the latter will allow you to *join* shapes by *intersecting*, *adding*, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you want is simpler than you think:

```
public class SetShape implements Shape {

    private final Shape shape;

    public SetShape(Shape shape) {
        this.shape = shape;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(double x, double y) {
        shape.contains(x, y);
    }

}
```

And do similar things for all methods in the [Shape](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) interface. Remember that whatever is passed to the constructor is *guaranteed* to contain an implementation of all those methods.